# How to get a specific user by their national Id

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I would like to add, edit and get users via an API I have created. I can add users and get all users added via API requests on Postman but I can't get data for a specific user when I request it on Postman as all I get is a null response with a 200 OK status. How can I be able to get a specific user's information using its national Id?

This is how my entity looks like;

```
public class users {

    @Id
    private String Id;

    @Field("nationalId")
    @JsonProperty("nationalId")
    private String nationalId;

    @Field("userName")
    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String userName;

    @Field("userEmail")
    @JsonProperty("userEmail")
    private String userEmail;

    @Field("userPin")
    @JsonProperty("userPin")
    private String userPin;

    @Field("userContact")
    @JsonProperty("userContact")
    private String userContact;

    @Field("imageUrl")
    @JsonProperty("imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Field("loanLimit")
    @JsonProperty("loanLimit")
    private String loanLimit;

}
```

My controller class looks like this;

```
class Controller {
        @Autowired
        private user_service User_Service;

        @PostMapping("/save_user")
        private users save (@RequestBody users Users){return User_Service.save(Users);}

        @PutMapping("/update_user")
        private users update (@RequestBody users Users){return User_Service.update(Users);}

        @GetMapping("/all")
        private List<users> getAllusers(){return User_Service.getAllusers();}

        @GetMapping("/user/{nationalId}")
        private Optional <users> getusers(@PathVariable String nationalId) {return User_Service.getusers(nationalId);}

        @DeleteMapping("/delete_user/{nationalId}")
        private void deleteUser (@PathVariable String nationalId){User_Service.deleteUser(nationalId);}

    }
```

My user service look like this;

```
public interface user_service {

users save (users Users);

users update (users Users);

List<users> getAllusers();

Optional<users> getusers(String nationalId);

void deleteUser (String nationalId);

}
```

Comment: Show us User_Service

Comment: Did you use repository ?

Comment: Share your user repository

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name attribute in PathVariable annotation as  `@PathVariable(name="nationalId")`

Comment: I think you don't need to do this since Spring 4.3 or smth

Comment: Please elaborate in your question which version of Spring are you using.

Comment: Do read this - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a method call like this to get a specific by national id.

```
Optional<user> getUserByNationalId(String nationalId);
```

for spring to understand what it is you want to fetch it cant figure it out by just passing in a string.

(And please rename your class `User`, and not `users`. The class represents a single user, and also please use camel casing)